# I want to delete data without refreshing whole page using ajax

Tags: laravel

I am new at Laravel, I am trying to delete data with ajax, when I click to delete button, the page is refreshing but data is deleting perfectly but that should not be reloaded.

**Controller**

```
public function destroy($id)
{
     $delete = Digitizing::where('id', $id)->delete();
     return back();
}
```

**HTML view**

```
<a  href="{{route('digitizing.delete',$digitizing->id)}}"   
            class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteConfirmation({{$digitizing->id}})">Delete</a>



<script type="text/javascript">
                    
     function deleteConfirmation(id) {
         Swal.fire({
              title: "Delete?",
              text: "Please ensure and then confirm!",
              type: "warning",
              showCancelButton: !0,
              confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
              cancelButtonText: "No, cancel!",
              reverseButtons: !0
              }).then(function (e) {

                  if (e.value === true) {
                       var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

                       $.ajax({
                       type: 'POST',
                       url: "{{url('digitizing/delete')}}/" + id,
                       data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN},
                       dataType: 'JSON',
                       success: function (results) {
                       if (results.success === true) {
                        swal("Done!", results.message, "success");
                       } else {
                         swal("Error!", results.message, "error");
                       }
                   }
              });
          } else {
              e.dismiss;
          }
      }, function (dismiss) {
           return false;
      })
   } 
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Zubair. A quick reminder that many of your questions are featuring embarrassing amounts of begging. Readers would rather than question authors do not engage in extended bouts of pleading, especially given that most people here are volunteers. Stick to technical writing please.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Delete wants a get method because you have to give only ID to delete.**
**WEB.PHP**
    Route::get('digitizing/delete/{id}','YourController@destroy');
    **SCRIPT**
        let id = $('#my_id').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "{{url('digitizing/delete')}}/" + id,
            data: {
                _token: '{{csrf_token()}}',
            },
            success: function () {
               alert('Successfully Deleted');
            }
    }).fail(function(){
      console.log('problem with route = digitizing/delete');
    });
```